# How do I refresh tables in SQLite Database Browser?

Tags: sqlite

Does anyone know if there's a way to force the SQLite Database Browser to refresh its data in 'Browse Data'.  I find I keep having to flick away and back from a given table to see an updated view of it when I change the data programatically.

Answer (score 9):

update to the latest version of SQLLite Database Browser and next to database button there is a refresh button! [image]

Comment: If you installed it through the software center, it means you dont have the latest version. You can find it here http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: just want to note that if the db has been deleted and recreated while the db browser is running, it will require opening the .sqlite3 file again to see an updated table. A simple refresh will not work in this case. I'm running version 3.11.99

Comment: ~Any idea how to do this in the _Database Structure_ tab?~ Just hit F5 and it refreshes the table structure as well!

Comment: Cmd + R if you're on a mac

Answer (score 1):

As @aalaap mentionned in their comment, simply press F5.